# Procedure or function Top100 has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to fix this old asp.net page and I keep getting 'Procedure or function Top100 has too many arguments specified. This error only happens when you click the 'Top 10' button the website I'm not sure what to do as I am pretty new to c#. And I don't know my way around it yet.

```cs
public SqlDataReader ExecuteQuery(string strSql)
{
    MsSqlConnection = OpenConnection();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = strSql;
    command.Connection = MsSqlConnection;
    MsSqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    return reader;
}
```

Top100 code:

```cs
public DataTable Top100(int nation, int class_)
{

    string strSql = "exec DragonRajaDB.dbo.Top100 " + Convert.ToInt32(nation) + "," + Convert.ToInt32(class_);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Lev", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Class", typeof(String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nation", typeof(String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Guild", typeof(String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GuildLogoURL", typeof(String)));
    using (SqlDataReader reader = ExecuteQuery(strSql))
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = i;
            dr[1] = reader.GetSqlString(0).Value;
            dr[2] = reader.GetSqlInt32(1).Value;
            int playerClass = reader.GetSqlInt32(2).Value;
            switch (playerClass)
            {
                case 0:
                    dr[3] = "Warrior";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    dr[3] = "Thief";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dr[3] = "Archer";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dr[3] = "Wizard";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    dr[3] = "Priest";
                    break;
                default:
                    dr[3] = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            dr[4] = reader.GetSqlString(3).Value;
            if (reader.GetSqlString(4).IsNull)
            {
                dr[5] = "";
                dr[6] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                dr[5] = reader.GetSqlString(4).Value;
                int guildCode = reader.GetSqlInt32(5).Value;
                dr[6] = "guildlogos/guild" + guildCode.ToString() + ".gif";
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```sql
USE [Dragonrajadb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Top100]    Script Date: 10/21/2014 11:02:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Top100]              
@nation int = 0


AS              
 DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)              

 SET @SQLString = N'SELECT top 100 name, lev, exp, nation from chr_info where name not in (''GM01'') '              
 if @nation <> 0        
 begin              
  if @nation = 6        
  begin        
   set @SQLString = @SQLString + ' and nation in (6,22,38,14,30,38)'           
  end        
  else if @nation = 3        
  begin        
   set @SQLString = @SQLString + ' and nation not in (4,20,12,28,36,6,22,38,14,30,38)'           
  end          
  else if @nation = 4        
  begin        
   set @SQLString = @SQLString + ' and nation in (4,20,12,28,36)'           
  end          
 end        
 set @SQLString = @SQLString + ' order by lev desc, exp desc'              
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Comment: Care to show us the definition of `DragonRajaDB.dbo.Top100`?

Comment: ... from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure `Top100` only has **one** parameter, i.e.: `nation`:

```sql
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Top100]              
@nation int = 0 -- just one parameter
AS
...
```

You're attempting to specify a second argument: `class`:

```cs
string strSql = "exec DragonRajaDB.dbo.Top100 " + nation + "," + class_;
```

So, remove the `class` argument:

```cs
string strSql = "exec DragonRajaDB.dbo.Top100 " + nation
```